# Fine tune GPT-2 Text Prediction for Conversational AI

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, chatbot, gpt-2

I am experimenting with the gpt-2 model's conditional text generation to tweak it for a good chatbot. I am using [nsheppard's code](https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2) for retraining it on my custom dataset.

I trained my model on a custom dataset of conversations that I pulled from my facebook data. I changed the sample length to 20 as they are dialogues during interactive conditional generation.

The dataset looks something like this:

```
 How are you 
 Hi Great and you 
 Am also good 
 So you re a graphic designer  
 Yeah 
 How can you contribute to making the game In d graphics aspect 
 Can you show me some of your work if u don t mind  
 Am planning to learn making it a motion type    
 U can go through my photos 
 K 
 Can you make animations for it  
 Flash animations to be specific 
 No please only stable ones 
 Ok
```

But, after the training when i try to chat with it, it is instead completing my sentences instead of replying to them.

```
User >>> bye
======================================== SAMPLE 1 ========================================
 and  
 hi 
 are there any positions in khrzh being appointed right now
```

I understand that the interactive_conditional_samples.py was built to complete the sentence based on the prompt, but I thought changing the dataset would work and sure it doesn't work.

train.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Usage:
#  PYTHONPATH=src ./train --dataset <file|directory|glob>

import argparse
import json
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import tqdm
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2

import model, sample, encoder
from load_dataset import load_dataset, Sampler
from accumulate import AccumulatingOptimizer
import memory_saving_gradients

CHECKPOINT_DIR = 'checkpoint'
SAMPLE_DIR = 'samples'


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Fine-tune GPT-2 on your custom dataset.',
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument('--dataset', metavar='PATH', type=str, required=True, help='Input file, directory, or glob pattern (utf-8 text, or preencoded .npz files).')
parser.add_argument('--model_name', metavar='MODEL', type=str, default='117M', help='Pretrained model name')
parser.add_argument('--combine', metavar='CHARS', type=int, default=50000, help='Concatenate input files with <|endoftext|> separator into chunks of this minimum size')

parser.add_argument('--batch_size', metavar='SIZE', type=int, default=1, help='Batch size')
parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', metavar='LR', type=float, default=0.00002, help='Learning rate for Adam')
parser.add_argument('--accumulate_gradients', metavar='N', type=int, default=1, help='Accumulate gradients across N minibatches.')
parser.add_argument('--memory_saving_gradients', default=False, action='store_true', help='Use gradient checkpointing to reduce vram usage.')
parser.add_argument('--only_train_transformer_layers', default=False, action='store_true', help='Restrict training to the transformer blocks.')
parser.add_argument('--optimizer', type=str, default='adam', help='Optimizer. <adam|sgd>.')
parser.add_argument('--noise', type=float, default=0.0, help='Add noise to input training data to regularize against typos.')

parser.add_argument('--top_k', type=int, default=40, help='K for top-k sampling.')
parser.add_argument('--top_p', type=float, default=0.0, help='P for top-p sampling. Overrides top_k if set > 0.')

parser.add_argument('--restore_from', type=str, default='latest', help='Either "latest", "fresh", or a path to a checkpoint file')
parser.add_argument('--run_name', type=str, default='run1', help='Run id. Name of subdirectory in checkpoint/ and samples/')
parser.add_argument('--sample_every', metavar='N', type=int, default=100, help='Generate samples every N steps')
parser.add_argument('--sample_length', metavar='TOKENS', type=int, default=1023, help='Sample this many tokens')
parser.add_argument('--sample_num', metavar='N', type=int, default=1, help='Generate this many samples')
parser.add_argument('--save_every', metavar='N', type=int, default=1000, help='Write a checkpoint every N steps')

parser.add_argument('--val_dataset', metavar='PATH', type=str, default=None, help='Dataset for validation loss, defaults to --dataset.')
parser.add_argument('--val_batch_size', metavar='SIZE', type=int, default=2, help='Batch size for validation.')
parser.add_argument('--val_batch_count', metavar='N', type=int, default=40, help='Number of batches for validation.')
parser.add_argument('--val_every', metavar='STEPS', type=int, default=0, help='Calculate validation loss every STEPS steps.')


def maketree(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except:
        pass


def randomize(context, hparams, p):
    if p > 0:
        mask = tf.random.uniform(shape=tf.shape(context)) < p
        noise = tf.random.uniform(shape=tf.shape(context), minval=0, maxval=hparams.n_vocab, dtype=tf.int32)
        return tf.where(mask, noise, context)
    else:
        return context


def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()
    enc = encoder.get_encoder(args.model_name)
    hparams = model.default_hparams()
    with open(os.path.join('models', args.model_name, 'hparams.json')) as f:
        hparams.override_from_dict(json.load(f))

    if args.sample_length > hparams.n_ctx:
        raise ValueError(
            "Can't get samples longer than window size: %s" % hparams.n_ctx)

    if args.model_name == '345M':
        args.memory_saving_gradients = True
        if args.optimizer == 'adam':
            args.only_train_transformer_layers = True

    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    config.graph_options.rewrite_options.layout_optimizer = rewriter_config_pb2.RewriterConfig.OFF
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        context = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, None])
        context_in = randomize(context, hparams, args.noise)
        output = model.model(hparams=hparams, X=context_in)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                labels=context[:, 1:], logits=output['logits'][:, :-1]))

        if args.val_every > 0:
            val_context = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.val_batch_size, None])
            val_output = model.model(hparams=hparams, X=val_context)
            val_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                    labels=val_context[:, 1:], logits=val_output['logits'][:, :-1]))
            val_loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('val_loss', val_loss)


        tf_sample = sample.sample_sequence(
            hparams=hparams,
            length=args.sample_length,
            context=context,
            batch_size=args.batch_size,
            temperature=1.0,
            top_k=args.top_k,
            top_p=args.top_p)

        all_vars = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if 'model' in v.name]
        train_vars = [v for v in all_vars if '/h' in v.name] if args.only_train_transformer_layers else all_vars

        if args.optimizer == 'adam':
            opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=args.learning_rate)
        elif args.optimizer == 'sgd':
            opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=args.learning_rate)
        else:
            exit('Bad optimizer:', args.optimizer)

        if args.accumulate_gradients > 1:
            if args.memory_saving_gradients:
                exit("Memory saving gradients are not implemented for gradient accumulation yet.")
            opt = AccumulatingOptimizer(
                opt=opt,
                var_list=train_vars)
            opt_reset = opt.reset()
            opt_compute = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
            opt_apply = opt.apply_gradients()
            summary_loss = tf.summary.scalar('loss', opt_apply)
        else:
            if args.memory_saving_gradients:
                opt_grads = memory_saving_gradients.gradients(loss, train_vars)
            else:
                opt_grads = tf.gradients(loss, train_vars)
            opt_grads = list(zip(opt_grads, train_vars))
            opt_apply = opt.apply_gradients(opt_grads)
            summary_loss = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

        summary_lr = tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', args.learning_rate)
        summaries = tf.summary.merge([summary_lr, summary_loss])

        summary_log = tf.summary.FileWriter(
            os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_DIR, args.run_name))

        saver = tf.train.Saver(
            var_list=all_vars,
            max_to_keep=5,
            keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=2)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        if args.restore_from == 'latest':
            ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(
                os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_DIR, args.run_name))
            if ckpt is None:
                # Get fresh GPT weights if new run.
                ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(
                    os.path.join('models', args.model_name))
        elif args.restore_from == 'fresh':
            ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(
                os.path.join('models', args.model_name))
        else:
            ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(args.restore_from)
        print('Loading checkpoint', ckpt)
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt)

        print('Loading dataset...')
        chunks = load_dataset(enc, args.dataset, args.combine)
        data_sampler = Sampler(chunks)
        if args.val_every > 0:
            val_chunks = load_dataset(enc, args.val_dataset, args.combine) if args.val_dataset else chunks
        print('dataset has', data_sampler.total_size, 'tokens')
        print('Training...')

        if args.val_every > 0:
            # Sample from validation set once with fixed seed to make
            # it deterministic during training as well as across runs.
            val_data_sampler = Sampler(val_chunks, seed=1)
            val_batches = [[val_data_sampler.sample(1024) for _ in range(args.val_batch_size)]
                           for _ in range(args.val_batch_count)]

        counter = 1
        counter_path = os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_DIR, args.run_name, 'counter')
        if os.path.exists(counter_path):
            # Load the step number if we're resuming a run
            # Add 1 so we don't immediately try to save again
            with open(counter_path, 'r') as fp:
                counter = int(fp.read()) + 1

        def save():
            maketree(os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_DIR, args.run_name))
            print(
                'Saving',
                os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_DIR, args.run_name,
                             'model-{}').format(counter))
            saver.save(
                sess,
                os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_DIR, args.run_name, 'model'),
                global_step=counter)
            with open(counter_path, 'w') as fp:
                fp.write(str(counter) + '\n')

        def generate_samples():
            print('Generating samples...')
            context_tokens = data_sampler.sample(1)
            all_text = []
            index = 0
            while index < args.sample_num:
                out = sess.run(
                    tf_sample,
                    feed_dict={context: args.batch_size * [context_tokens]})
                for i in range(min(args.sample_num - index, args.batch_size)):
                    text = enc.decode(out[i])
                    text = '======== SAMPLE {} ========\n{}\n'.format(
                        index + 1, text)
                    all_text.append(text)
                    index += 1
            print(text)
            maketree(os.path.join(SAMPLE_DIR, args.run_name))
            with open(
                    os.path.join(SAMPLE_DIR, args.run_name,
                                 'samples-{}').format(counter), 'w') as fp:
                fp.write('\n'.join(all_text))

        def validation():
            print('Calculating validation loss...')
            losses = []
            for batch in tqdm.tqdm(val_batches):
                losses.append(sess.run(val_loss, feed_dict={val_context: batch}))
            v_val_loss = np.mean(losses)
            v_summary = sess.run(val_loss_summary, feed_dict={val_loss: v_val_loss})
            summary_log.add_summary(v_summary, counter)
            summary_log.flush()
            print(
                '[{counter} | {time:2.2f}] validation loss = {loss:2.2f}'
                .format(
                    counter=counter,
                    time=time.time() - start_time,
                    loss=v_val_loss))

        def sample_batch():
            return [data_sampler.sample(1024) for _ in range(args.batch_size)]


        avg_loss = (0.0, 0.0)
        start_time = time.time()

        try:
            while True:
                if counter % args.save_every == 0:
                    save()
                if counter % args.sample_every == 0:
                    generate_samples()
                if args.val_every > 0 and (counter % args.val_every == 0 or counter == 1):
                    validation()

                if args.accumulate_gradients > 1:
                    sess.run(opt_reset)
                    for _ in range(args.accumulate_gradients):
                        sess.run(
                            opt_compute, feed_dict={context: sample_batch()})
                    (v_loss, v_summary) = sess.run((opt_apply, summaries))
                else:
                    (_, v_loss, v_summary) = sess.run(
                        (opt_apply, loss, summaries),
                        feed_dict={context: sample_batch()})

                summary_log.add_summary(v_summary, counter)

                avg_loss = (avg_loss[0] * 0.99 + v_loss,
                            avg_loss[1] * 0.99 + 1.0)

                print(
                    '[{counter} | {time:2.2f}] loss={loss:2.2f} avg={avg:2.2f}'
                    .format(
                        counter=counter,
                        time=time.time() - start_time,
                        loss=v_loss,
                        avg=avg_loss[0] / avg_loss[1]))

                counter += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('interrupted')
            save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

sample.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

import model

def top_k_logits(logits, k):
    if k == 0:
        # no truncation
        return logits

    def _top_k():
        values, _ = tf.nn.top_k(logits, k=k)
        min_values = values[:, -1, tf.newaxis]
        return tf.where(
            logits < min_values,
            tf.ones_like(logits, dtype=logits.dtype) * -1e10,
            logits,
        )
    return tf.cond(
       tf.equal(k, 0),
       lambda: logits,
       lambda: _top_k(),
    )


def top_p_logits(logits, p):
    with tf.variable_scope('top_p_logits'):
        logits_sort = tf.sort(logits, direction='DESCENDING')
        probs_sort = tf.nn.softmax(logits_sort)
        probs_sums = tf.cumsum(probs_sort, axis=1, exclusive=True)
        logits_masked = tf.where(probs_sums < p, logits_sort, tf.ones_like(logits_sort)*1000) # [batchsize, vocab]
        min_logits = tf.reduce_min(logits_masked, axis=1, keepdims=True) # [batchsize, 1]
        return tf.where(
            logits < min_logits,
            tf.ones_like(logits, dtype=logits.dtype) * -1e10,
            logits,
        )


def sample_sequence(*, hparams, length, start_token=None, batch_size=None, context=None, temperature=1, top_k=0, top_p=0.0):
    if start_token is None:
        assert context is not None, 'Specify exactly one of start_token and context!'
    else:
        assert context is None, 'Specify exactly one of start_token and context!'
        context = tf.fill([batch_size, 1], start_token)

    def step(hparams, tokens, past=None):
        lm_output = model.model(hparams=hparams, X=tokens, past=past, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)

        logits = lm_output['logits'][:, :, :hparams.n_vocab]
        presents = lm_output['present']
        presents.set_shape(model.past_shape(hparams=hparams, batch_size=batch_size))
        return {
            'logits': logits,
            'presents': presents,
        }

    with tf.name_scope('sample_sequence'):
        # Don't feed the last context token -- leave that to the loop below
        # TODO: Would be slightly faster if we called step on the entire context,
        # rather than leaving the last token transformer calculation to the while loop.
        context_output = step(hparams, context[:, :-1])

        def body(past, prev, output):
            next_outputs = step(hparams, prev[:, tf.newaxis], past=past)
            logits = next_outputs['logits'][:, -1, :]  / tf.to_float(temperature)
            if top_p > 0.0:
                logits = top_p_logits(logits, p=top_p)
            else:
                logits = top_k_logits(logits, k=top_k)
            samples = tf.multinomial(logits, num_samples=1, output_dtype=tf.int32)
            return [
                tf.concat([past, next_outputs['presents']], axis=-2),
                tf.squeeze(samples, axis=[1]),
                tf.concat([output, samples], axis=1),
            ]

        def cond(*args):
            return True

        _, _, tokens = tf.while_loop(
            cond=cond, body=body,
            maximum_iterations=length,
            loop_vars=[
                context_output['presents'],
                context[:, -1],
                context,
            ],
            shape_invariants=[
                tf.TensorShape(model.past_shape(hparams=hparams, batch_size=batch_size)),
                tf.TensorShape([batch_size]),
                tf.TensorShape([batch_size, None]),
            ],
            back_prop=False,
        )

        return tokens
```

interactive_conditional_samples.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import fire
import json
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import model, sample, encoder

def interact_model(
    model_name='chatbot',
    seed=None,
    nsamples=1,
    batch_size=1,
    length=20,
    temperature=1,
    top_k=0,
    top_p=0.0
):
    """
    Interactively run the model
    :model_name=chatbot : String, which model to use
    :seed=None : Integer seed for random number generators, fix seed to reproduce
     results
    :nsamples=1 : Number of samples to return total
    :batch_size=1 : Number of batches (only affects speed/memory).  Must divide nsamples.
    :length=None : Number of tokens in generated text, if None (default), is
     determined by model hyperparameters
    :temperature=1 : Float value controlling randomness in boltzmann
     distribution. Lower temperature results in less random completions. As the
     temperature approaches zero, the model will become deterministic and
     repetitive. Higher temperature results in more random completions.
    :top_k=0 : Integer value controlling diversity. 1 means only 1 word is
     considered for each step (token), resulting in deterministic completions,
     while 40 means 40 words are considered at each step. 0 (default) is a
     special setting meaning no restrictions. 40 generally is a good value.
    :top_p=0.0 : Float value controlling diversity. Implements nucleus sampling,
     overriding top_k if set to a value > 0. A good setting is 0.9.
    """
    if batch_size is None:
        batch_size = 1
    assert nsamples % batch_size == 0

    enc = encoder.get_encoder(model_name)
    hparams = model.default_hparams()
    with open(os.path.join('models', model_name, 'hparams.json')) as f:
        hparams.override_from_dict(json.load(f))

    if length is None:
        length = hparams.n_ctx // 2
    elif length > hparams.n_ctx:
        raise ValueError("Can't get samples longer than window size: %s" % hparams.n_ctx)

    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        context = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, None])
        np.random.seed(seed)
        tf.set_random_seed(seed)
        output = sample.sample_sequence(
            hparams=hparams, length=length,
            context=context,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            temperature=temperature, top_k=top_k, top_p=top_p
        )

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.join('models', model_name))
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt)

        while True:
            raw_text = input("User >>> ")
            while not raw_text:
                print('Prompt should not be empty!')
                raw_text = input("User >>> ")
            context_tokens = enc.encode(raw_text)
            generated = 0
            for _ in range(nsamples // batch_size):
                out = sess.run(output, feed_dict={
                    context: [context_tokens for _ in range(batch_size)]
                })[:, len(context_tokens):]
                for i in range(batch_size):
                    generated += 1
                    text = enc.decode(out[i])
                    print("=" * 40 + " SAMPLE " + str(generated) + " " + "=" * 40)
                    print(text)
            print("=" * 80)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(interact_model)
```

How can I tweak the code to get it working like a chatbot? I am guessing it has something to do with the context part in sample.py, though i am unsure how is this going to work.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question now, but I have successfully tuned many Q&A style datasets on GPT-2 and have a suggestion that will work for future people who find this question.

GPT-2 reads unstructured text data, but it is *very* good at inferring and obeying structure in that data. Your issue is basically that you are not terminating your input lines with an identifier that GPT-2 understands, so it continues the sentence.

A simple way to fix this would be to annotate your dataset. Really anything with stop/start tokens will work, but you should also annotate the speaker identities. I would just do something like this:

```
A: How are you <EOL>
B: Hi Great and you <EOL>
A: Am also good <EOL>
B: So you re a graphic designer <EOL>
B: Another line from B <EOL>
```

The other benefit of this approach is that GPT-2 will learn multi-line input/output, and the different identities of the two conversants.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, all model sees is looking at the series of text you gave it, and trying to predict next most likely /token to be exact. It's not an encoder-decoder architecture. What you require is fine-tuning this architecture for a chatbot architecture.The only implementation I found regarding that one is here. But's it's done in pytorch so i am afraid it won't be what you are wanting.

https://medium.com/huggingface/how-to-build-a-state-of-the-art-conversational-ai-with-transfer-learning-2d818ac26313

Comment: my friend had suggested using a different loss function which compares the required reply with the predicted reply and training it on that loss. Do you think it would work? P.S. I had seen that pytorch implementation but it was only able to answer questions based on its persona and i am not too familiar with pytorch so i had no idea finutuning that implementation. Also i found this https://github.com/openai/gpt-2/pull/77?fbclid=IwAR2343P3h7eZL0c6gDfB7PkUeLf8UEtdsLJAXQN_aM1CreGZfk4XmXsi3Tw